# Reposition stimuli on a screen, relative to the number of pixels per visual degree

Tags: javascript, css

I have a variable stored called "PxPerDegree" which is how many pixels there are in a single visual degree on a computer screen, that I can use to calculate how big/small I need to present images so that they stay the same size, no matter the size of the screen that they are being presented on.

I am trying to create a 'ring' of 6 zones (Zone 1 is the top image, Zone 2 is the bottom, Zone 3 is the upper right, Zone 4 is lower right, Zone 5 is upper left and Zone 6 is lower left), and I want this imaginary ring to be 10.2 visual degrees in diameter.

I am using .css to reposition the stimuli according to the number of pixels in a degree. Zones 3,4,5,6 are moving inward and outward, but zones 1 and 2 are not moving at all.

I know that the maths might be off here, but basically, I just want to be able to reposition these stimuli systematically as a starting point. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be forever grateful!

```
var mainZoneTop1 = parseFloat(mainZone.css('top'));
    var mainZoneLeft1 = parseFloat(mainZone.css('left'));
    var mainZoneTop2 = parseFloat(mainZone2.css('top'));
    var mainZoneLeft2 = parseFloat(mainZone2.css('left'));
    var mainZoneTop3 = parseFloat(mainZone3.css('top'));
    var mainZoneLeft3 = parseFloat(mainZone3.css('left'));
    var mainZoneTop4 = parseFloat(mainZone4.css('top'));
    var mainZoneLeft4 = parseFloat(mainZone4.css('left'));
    var mainZoneTop5 = parseFloat(mainZone5.css('top'));
    var mainZoneLeft5 = parseFloat(mainZone5.css('left'));
    var mainZoneTop6 = parseFloat(mainZone6.css('top'));
    var mainZoneLeft6 = parseFloat(mainZone6.css('left'));
    
    var radius = -5.1*PxPerDeg;
    

    
    $(container + ' .Zone1').css('top', (mainZoneTop1 + radius).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone1').css('left', (mainZoneLeft1 + 0).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone2').css('top', (mainZoneTop2 -radius).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone2').css('left', (mainZoneLeft2 + 0).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone3').css('top', (mainZoneTop3 + -radius).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone3').css('left', (mainZoneLeft3 + -radius*.866).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone4').css('top', (mainZoneTop4 + -radius).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone4').css('left', (mainZoneLeft4 + -radius*.866).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone5').css('top', (mainZoneTop5 + radius).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone5').css('left', (mainZoneLeft5 + radius*.866).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone6').css('top', (mainZoneTop6 + radius).toString() + 'px');
    $(container + ' .Zone6').css('left', (mainZoneLeft6 + radius*.866).toString() + 'px');
```

UPDATE - here's the newest code - same problems, but this is the code that deals with the entirety of the presentation of the stimuli.

```
var mainStimuliWidth = 2.3;
var mainStimuliHeight = 2.3;


gorillaTaskBuilder.onScreenFinish((spreadsheet: any, rowIndex: number, screenIndex: number, row: any, container: string, correct: boolean) => {
    if (row.display == _requiredRTDisplay) {
        if (screenIndex == _requiredRTScreen) {
            var reactionTimeBlue: number = gorilla.readStopwatch();
            gorilla.store(_RTKeyBlue, reactionTimeBlue, false);
            var reactionTimeRed: number = gorilla.readStopwatch();
            gorilla.store(_RTKeyRed, reactionTimeRed, false);
        }
    }
    if (row.display == _requiredRTDisplay2) {
        if (screenIndex == _requiredRTScreen2) {
            var reactionTimeBlueK: number = gorilla.readStopwatch();
            gorilla.store(_RTKeyBlueK, reactionTimeBlueK, false);
            var reactionTimeRedK: number = gorilla.readStopwatch();
            gorilla.store(_RTKeyRedK, reactionTimeRedK, false);
        }

    }

});

gorillaTaskBuilder.onScreenStart((spreadsheet: any, rowIndex: number, screenIndex: number, row: any, container: string) => {
    $('body').css('background-color', BACKGROUND_COLOUR);
    $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, span').css('color', TEXT_COLOUR);
    if(row.display == _requiredRTDisplay){
        if(screenIndex == _requiredRTScreen){
        $(window).resize();
        var PxPerDeg = gorilla.retrieve('pixels_per_degree', null, true)
        var mainZone = $(container + ' .Zone1');
        var initialTop = $(container + ' .Zone1').css('top');
        mainZone.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        mainZone.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        var mainZoneParentHeight = mainZone.parent().height();
        var mainZoneParentWidth = mainZone.parent().width();
        var currentStimuliWidth = mainZone.width();
        var currentStimuliHeight = mainZone.height();
        console.log(currentStimuliHeight);
                
        var centerOfContainerH = (mainZoneParentHeight - currentStimuliHeight - parseFloat(initialTop)) / 2;
        var centerOfContainerW = (mainZoneParentWidth - currentStimuliWidth) / 2;
            
        mainZone.css('left', centerOfContainerW.toString() + 'px');
        mainZone.css('top', centerOfContainerH.toString() + 'px');
        var mainZone2 = $(container + ' .Zone2');
        var initialTop2 = $(container + ' .Zone2').css('top');
        mainZone2.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        mainZone2.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        var mainZoneParentHeight2 = mainZone2.parent().height();
        var mainZoneParentWidth2 = mainZone2.parent().width();
        var currentStimuliWidth2 = mainZone2.width();
        var currentStimuliHeight2 = mainZone2.height();
        console.log(currentStimuliHeight2);
                
        var centerOfContainerH2 = (mainZoneParentHeight2 - currentStimuliHeight2 - parseFloat(initialTop2)) / 2;
        var centerOfContainerW2 = (mainZoneParentWidth2 - currentStimuliWidth2) / 2;
            
        mainZone2.css('left', centerOfContainerW2.toString() + 'px');
        mainZone2.css('top', centerOfContainerH2.toString() + 'px');        
        var mainZone3 = $(container + ' .Zone3');
        var initialTop3 = $(container + ' .Zone3').css('top');
        mainZone3.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        mainZone3.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        var mainZoneParentHeight3 = mainZone3.parent().height();
        var mainZoneParentWidth3 = mainZone3.parent().width();
        var currentStimuliWidth3 = mainZone3.width();
        var currentStimuliHeight3 = mainZone3.height();
        console.log(currentStimuliHeight3);
                
        var centerOfContainerH3 = (mainZoneParentHeight3 - currentStimuliHeight3 - parseFloat(initialTop3)) / 2;
        var centerOfContainerW3 = (mainZoneParentWidth3 - currentStimuliWidth3) / 2;
            
        mainZone3.css('left', centerOfContainerW3.toString() + 'px');
        mainZone3.css('top', centerOfContainerH3.toString() + 'px');   
        var mainZone4 = $(container + ' .Zone4');
        var initialTop4 = $(container + ' .Zone4').css('top');
        mainZone4.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        mainZone4.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        var mainZoneParentHeight4 = mainZone4.parent().height();
        var mainZoneParentWidth4 = mainZone4.parent().width();
        var currentStimuliWidth4 = mainZone4.width();
        var currentStimuliHeight4 = mainZone4.height();
        console.log(currentStimuliHeight4);
                
        var centerOfContainerH4 = (mainZoneParentHeight4 - currentStimuliHeight4 - parseFloat(initialTop4)) / 2;
        var centerOfContainerW4 = (mainZoneParentWidth4 - currentStimuliWidth4) / 2;
            
        mainZone4.css('left', centerOfContainerW4.toString() + 'px');
        mainZone4.css('top', centerOfContainerH4.toString() + 'px');       
        var mainZone5 = $(container + ' .Zone5');
        var initialTop5 = $(container + ' .Zone5').css('top');
        mainZone5.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        mainZone5.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        var mainZoneParentHeight5 = mainZone5.parent().height();
        var mainZoneParentWidth5 = mainZone5.parent().width();
        var currentStimuliWidth5 = mainZone5.width();
        var currentStimuliHeight5 = mainZone5.height();
        console.log(currentStimuliHeight5);
                
        var centerOfContainerH5 = (mainZoneParentHeight5 - currentStimuliHeight5 - parseFloat(initialTop5)) / 2;
        var centerOfContainerW5 = (mainZoneParentWidth5 - currentStimuliWidth5) / 2;
            
        mainZone5.css('left', centerOfContainerW5.toString() + 'px');
        mainZone5.css('top', centerOfContainerH5.toString() + 'px');   
        var mainZone6 = $(container + ' .Zone6');
        var initialTop6 = $(container + ' .Zone6').css('top');
        mainZone6.css('height', (mainStimuliHeight * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        mainZone6.css('width', (mainStimuliWidth * PxPerDeg).toString() + 'px');
        var mainZoneParentHeight6 = mainZone6.parent().height();
        var mainZoneParentWidth6 = mainZone6.parent().width();
        var currentStimuliWidth6 = mainZone6.width();
        var currentStimuliHeight6 = mainZone6.height();
        console.log(currentStimuliHeight6);
                
        var centerOfContainerH6 = (mainZoneParentHeight6 - currentStimuliHeight6 - parseFloat(initialTop6)) / 2;
        var centerOfContainerW6 = (mainZoneParentWidth6 - currentStimuliWidth6) / 2;
            
        mainZone6.css('left', centerOfContainerW6.toString() + 'px');
        mainZone6.css('top', centerOfContainerH6.toString() + 'px');  
        
         var mainZoneTop = parseFloat(mainZone.css('top'));
         var mainZoneLeft = parseFloat(mainZone.css('left'));
         var radiusNeg = -5.05*PxPerDeg;
         var radiusPos = 5.05*PxPerDeg;
         var hypotenuse_calc = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((5.05*PxPerDeg), 2) + Math.pow(((5.05*PxPerDeg) / 2),2));
        

        
        $(container + ' .Zone1').css('top', (mainZoneTop + radiusNeg).toString() + 'px');
        $(container + ' .Zone2').css('top', (mainZoneTop + radiusPos).toString() +  'px');
        $(container + ' .Zone3').css('top', (mainZoneTop + radiusNeg).toString() + 'px');
        $(container + ' .Zone3').css('left', (mainZoneLeft + radiusNeg*.866).toString() + 'px');
        $(container + ' .Zone4').css('top', (mainZoneTop + radiusNeg).toString() + 'px');
        $(container + ' .Zone4').css('left', (mainZoneLeft + radiusNeg*.866).toString() + 'px');
        $(container + ' .Zone5').css('top', (mainZoneTop + radiusPos).toString() + 'px');
        $(container + ' .Zone5').css('left', (mainZoneLeft + radiusPos*.866).toString() + 'px');
        $(container + ' .Zone6').css('top', (mainZoneTop + radiusPos).toString() + 'px');
        $(container + ' .Zone6').css('left', (mainZoneLeft + radiusPos*.866).toString() + 'px');
        
                
   
        
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                
           
                
            }, 16);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add you HTML structure and any relevant CSS.

Comment: Sure! Just added the extra code for additional context. That's all I have access to, unfortunately - I'm coding alongside a GUI.